# Drop year from POSIXct and plot ts data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, lubridate

I'm trying to drop year from a multiyear data frame and plot day-month on x axis with geom_smooth() calculated for different years.

My data structure, initially looks like this:

```
> str(pmWaw)
'data.frame':   52488 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date  : POSIXct, format: "2014-01-01 00:00:00" "2014-01-01 00:00:00" "2014-01-01 00:00:00" "2014-01-01 01:00:00" ...
 $ stacja: Factor w/ 273 levels "DsWrocKorzA",..: 26 27 129 26 27 129 26 27 129 26 ...
 $ pm25  : num  100 63 NA 69 36 NA 41 31 NA 37 ...
 $ pm10  : num  122 68 79 77 38 90 43 32 39 38 ...
 $ season: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "spring (MAM)"<..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

Using `lubridate` I added year and month as separate variables:

```
library(lubridate)    
pmWaw$year<- year(pmWaw$date)
pmWaw$month<- month(pmWaw$date)
```

Next, using a code found here on stackoverflow I calculated a month and day variable in `%m-%d` format:

```
pmWaw$month.day<-format(pmWaw$date, format="%m-%d")

#check new variable type:
> typeof(pmWaw$month.day)
[1] "character"
```

Eventually data frame I work with is this:

```
> head(pmWaw)
                 date         stacja pm25 pm10       season year month month.day
1 2014-01-01 00:00:00 MzWarNiepodKom  100  122 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
2 2014-01-01 00:00:00 MzWarszUrsynow   63   68 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
3 2014-01-01 00:00:00 MzWarTarKondra   NA   79 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
4 2014-01-01 01:00:00 MzWarNiepodKom   69   77 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
5 2014-01-01 01:00:00 MzWarszUrsynow   36   38 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
6 2014-01-01 01:00:00 MzWarTarKondra   NA   90 winter (DJF) 2014     1     01-01
> tail(pmWaw)
                     date       stacja pm25 pm10       season year month month.day
52483 2015-12-30 22:00:00 MzWarAlNiepo   36   47 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
52484 2015-12-30 22:00:00 MzWarKondrat   26   29 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
52485 2015-12-30 22:00:00 MzWarWokalna   36   44 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
52486 2015-12-30 23:00:00 MzWarAlNiepo   39   59 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
52487 2015-12-30 23:00:00 MzWarKondrat   36   39 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
52488 2015-12-30 23:00:00 MzWarWokalna   40   49 winter (DJF) 2015    12     12-30
```

Passing new values to ggplot gives me three issues:

```
ggplot(pmWaw, aes(x=month.day, y=pm25)) + 
geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) +
geom_smooth()
```

[image]

First (minor) problem: month.day is a char type variable and ggplot won't recognize it's initial time series nature. This I can probably overcome by manually setting scale labels to months.

Second (major) problem geom_smooth() is not calculated at all and I can't figure out why?

Third (major) problem is I can't work out a solution to add `year` as a grouping variable for two separate smoothed lines (mostly because geom_smooth is not there at all).

My guess is, that the source of all problems lies somewhere in the way how I extracted month and day format and ended up with a character class variable.

Could anyone help me fix it? Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a solution to work with:

```
ggplot(pmWaw, aes(x=month.day, y=pm25, group = year)) + 
geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
geom_smooth(aes(color=factor(year)))
```

solves issues 2 and 3 - geom smooth is there and I can distinguish years. Probably not the best solution but might be a good place to start

[image]